# Получение разницы во времени между разными днями| python datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Мне нужно вычислить разницу между 2 датами во времени, но не понимаю, как сделать это, если разница затрагивает несколько дней или месяцев.

Приведу код:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time       
a = input()
if a == "Записать":
    time = datetime.now(tz=None)
    time = datetime.strftime(time, '%d %H:%M:%S')
    time = str(time)
    f = open("C:/python/time.txt", "w")
    f.write(time)
    f.close()
    print(time)
elif a == "Сколько":
    f = open("C:/python/time.txt", "r")
    time1 = f.read()
    f.close()
    time1 = datetime.strptime(time1, "%d %H:%M:%S")
    time2 = datetime.now(tz=None)
    time2 = datetime.strftime(time2, '%d %H:%M:%S')
    time2 = datetime.strptime(time2, "%d %H:%M:%S")
    time_delta = time2 - time1
    time_delta = str(time_delta)
    time_delta = datetime.strptime(time_delta, "%H:%M:%S")
    timer = "1:00:00"
    timer = datetime.strptime(timer, "%H:%M:%S")
    if time_delta > timer:
        print("Прошло больше часа!")

    elif time_delta < timer:
        time_delta = timer - time_delta
        time_delta = str(time_delta)
        time_delta = datetime.strptime(time_delta, "%H:%M:%S").time()
        time_delta = str(time_delta)
        print("Прошло меньше часа, осталось " + time_delta)
```

Он будет работать только в том случае, если день остаётся одинаковым, но выдаёт ошибку ValueError: time data '1 day, 0:00:26' does not match format '%H:%M:%S', если день будет другим. Проба time_delta не удалась, ибо насколько я понимаю, он может вычислять только или разницу в днях или разнцу во времени, по крайней мере так я понял

Comment: у вас там минус 1 день ?

Comment: Ошибка сообщает о том, что Вы на шаблон `%H:%M:%S` подаете строку `-1 day, 0:00:26`. Шаблон принимает только часы, минуты и секунды. Вообще `-1` день Вы не возьмете даже `%d %H:%M:%S`. Записывайте полную дату и время, которые потом будете сравнивать.

Comment: @AndyPavlov ,да, -1 - это я протупил,, но я всё равно немного не понимаю, как действовать. К примеру если код будет 
'time_delta = datetime.strptime(time_delta, "%d %H:%M:%S")' -  ошибка будет происходить, если разница во времени менее 1 дня, а если код будет
'time_delta = datetime.strptime(time_delta, "%H:%M:%S")' - ошибка будет происходить, если разница во времени более дня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код можно упростить. Не надо лишний раз переводить в строки, потом обратно.

В "записать" Вы получаете текущее время через `datetime.now()`. Дальше в строку в ISO-формате `now.isoformat()` и записываем в файл.

По считыванию обратный процесс. Прочитали, преобразовали ISO-формат в переменную `before = datetime.fromisoformat(f.read())`. Дальше берем разницу. Она будет в формате объекта `timedelta`. Ее сравниваем с `timedelta(hours=1)` в один час. По итогам выводим результат.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a = input('Введите Записать или Сколько: ')
if a == 'Записать':
    now = datetime.now()
    with open('time.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(now.isoformat())  # Преобразуем в строку. Получаем время в ISO формате
elif a == 'Сколько':
    with open('time.txt', 'r') as f:
        before = datetime.fromisoformat(f.read())  # Считываем в ISO формате
    delta = datetime.now() - before
    if delta > timedelta(hours=1):
        print('Прошло больше часа!')
    else:
        print('Прошло меньше часа, осталось {} '.format(timedelta(hours=1) - delta))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам, правда. А то промучился с этим часов 5-6 и уже был готов всё бросить